# Error: ./setup.sh: line 23: [: /home/jessy/actions-runner/cd: binary operator expected

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm using GitHub workflow for python but I'm getting this error while installing. What is the exact reason for this error? I google it but I couldn't found.

```
Error: ./setup.sh: line 23: [: /home/jainmiah/actions-runner/cd: binary operator expected
```

Here is my workflow yaml:

```
name: Python package

on:
  push:
    branches: [ $default-branch ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ $default-branch ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
```

[image]

Comment: Please show a bit more context around the error, what you tried already and which command exactly is causing this error.

Comment: @rethab, I added the  logs. Thank You.

Comment: In your workflow, you're saying `runs-on: ubuntu-latest`. In your first error message it talks about `/home/jessy` and the screenshots mention `/home/jainmiah`. Could you please create one consistent reproducing example?

Comment: @rethab it's modified to jainmiah. Actually what could be the problem.

Comment: I would start by looking at the `setup-python` action and take the code from there to run it on your runner directly. That is, not trigger your code with GH Actions, but SSH into your runner and run the steps from your workflow manually. I also see some "permission denied" in your logs, so that might give another hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can [enable workflow and step debug logging](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging), by setting the following secrets in the repository that contains the workflow:

```
ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG = true
ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG   = true
```

That way, you will see exactly *where* this error message is triggered.

Comment: Where should I add these two lines in the YAML file? in the beginning or in the jobs?

Comment: @jessy Those are not in the action yaml file. They are in your repository, as secrets (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets)

Comment: I added both ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG & ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG to value area in secrets.